# Updating label from module in another thread

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update a label which is running in the UI thread from a Module... my code works fine if its within the Main Form but I'd like to try and keep my code tidy by not having it all within the Main Form and splitting it out into Modules.

So if I have the below in my Main Form it works:

```
Private threadingExecuteManualScan As Thread

Public Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click

        threadingExecuteManualScan = New Thread(AddressOf executeManualScanThread)
        threadingExecuteManualScan.IsBackground = True
        threadingExecuteManualScan.Start()

End Sub

Delegate Sub SetTextDelegate(ByVal textString As String)

Private Sub updateTextBox(ByVal stringValue As String)

        Dim textDelegate As New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf updateTextBox)
        form_Main.BeginInvoke(textDelegate, stringValue)

End Sub

Public Sub executeManualScanThread()

    updateTextBox("Update Label With This String")

End Sub
```

I'd like to move all of it to a Module except for:

```
Public Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click

        threadingExecuteManualScan = New Thread(AddressOf executeManualScanThread)
        threadingExecuteManualScan.IsBackground = True
        threadingExecuteManualScan.Start()

End Sub
```

But when I do the Invoke.Required never returns a true value which then doesn't update my label on my Main Form.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Ben

**UPDATED**

My Main Form Contains this:

```
Public Class form_Main

Delegate Sub SetTextDelegate(ByVal args As String)
Private threadingExecuteManualScan As Thread

Public Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click

        threadingExecuteManualScan = New Thread(AddressOf executeManualScanThread)
        threadingExecuteManualScan.IsBackground = True
        threadingExecuteManualScan.Start()

End Sub

Public Sub updateTextBox(ByVal stringValue As String)

        Dim textDelegate As New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf updateTextBox)
        me.BeginInvoke(textDelegate, stringValue)

End Sub

End Class
```

And My Module:

```
Module module_Helper_Threading

Public Sub executeManualScanThread()

        'Some Database Work
        form_Main.SetTextBoxInfo("Report Back - Step 1")
        'Some More Database Work
        form_Main.SetTextBoxInfo("Report Back - Step 2")
        'etc

End Sub

End Module
```

This however causes an error:

```
Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
```

Comment: How are you referencing your form_Main now that the code is inside a module? If you've switched to using the default instance of the form, that's your problem right there as they are thread-static, and a new instance is being created for each thread.

Comment: form_Main is a *type name*, not a reference to the form that the user is looking at.  This always goes wrong in VB.NET when you start using threads.  If you absolutely have to then use Application.OpenForms(0) instead to get a valid reference to form whose Invoke() method is going to work.  And don't use InvokeRequired, that's cargo cult, you know it should be True.  And don't use Invoke(), no point in slowing down your thread, use BeginInvoke().  BackgroundWorker is a decent class to help you avoid shooting your foot like this.

Comment: I'd add form_Main.label etc.... how else could I reference it?

Comment: I updated my code above to reflect your suggestions but I now receive the error: `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created`.

Comment: Invoke will not work before any call to `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @jaminben, declare a variable of type `form_Main` inside your module, and set it to `Me` inside your form_Main constructor or `Load` event handler call. Now you have a concrete reference to the correct instance of `form_Main`. Having said that, you're not doing yourself any favours by moving out the code which legitimately belongs in `form_Main` to an outside module. It's fine to move the long-running routine which you want to run on the background thread into a class of its own, but calling that routine and updating own UI elements based on the result is the responsibility of `form_Main`.

Comment: @ Kirill, I've created lots of methods in a module so my Main Form didn't get over crowed (for example I have lots of SQL database calls, string cleaning functions, regex patterns etc). I was then planning on calling these methods in threads from the Main Form and updating the UI so the user knows what's happening in the background. Have I totally done this wrong? Should all these methods be located in the Main Form? I figured I could call these methods from the Main Form and then have them report back to the Main Form.

Comment: You could fix this with a background worker. ..

Comment: Also put all data calls in a data class, its a good practice to keep data calls and such out of the main class.

Comment: @jaminben, you have the right ideas in terms of trying not to cram too much into a single class. Separation of concerns is important. If you have a bunch of database calls, it's a good idea to move them out of the main form. Just make sure that any of the code which *actually updates* the main form is stripped out of those routines and remains inside the main form (some refactoring will be necessary). Same with your "scan" functionality - its "meat" can reside in a class of its own, but when it comes to reporting progress, that responsibility falls squarely on the form which triggers the scan.

Comment: Ok, So if all the database calls are stored outside of the Main Form but I want these calls to report back every so often to the Main Form how can I do that? I'm guessing I would create my method in the Main Form and call that method from the database code and pass information back to it.

Comment: @jaminben, long-running operations which need to report progress are a good fit for `System.Threading.Progress/IProgress`, where the long-running method reports the progress and the calling (i.e. UI) code gets to decide how to handle the progress being reported. Having said that a lot of the time simply refactoring the code to break up the long-running operation into smaller pieces provides you with enough opportunities to hook up some intermediate progress reporting between individual calls.

Comment: I've updated my main question with a different approach.

Comment: @jaminben, like I said, if you have code declared outside of `form_Main` manipulating UI elements which belong to `form_Main` (or any UI for that matter), that's a red flag (your classes are too tightly coupled, concerns are not well-separated). What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm only a weekend coder and just play with it but I'm more confused now than I was before I asked the question. I'm targeting .NET 4.5. I'm not manipulating the UI from outside `form_Main` now so it should be better shouldn't it? I just passing a string variable back to the `form_Main` element which should then get displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's amusing that the very first version of the code you posted was also the best.

Rather than going into a lengthy discussion about how things could be improved let me present a rewrite of your current code which would achieve the main goal and get you up and running, quickly:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class form_Main

  Private Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click() Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click
    Dim t As New Thread(Sub() module_Helper_Threading.executeManualScanThread(Me))

    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start()
  End Sub

  Public Sub SetTextBoxInfo(stringValue As String)
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() Me.TextBox.Text = stringValue)
  End Sub

End Class

Module module_Helper_Threading

  Public Sub executeManualScanThread(form_Main As form_Main)

    'Some Database Work
    Thread.Sleep(1000)

    form_Main.SetTextBoxInfo("Report Back - Step 1")

    'Some More Database Work
    Thread.Sleep(1000)

    form_Main.SetTextBoxInfo("Report Back - Step 2")
    'etc

  End Sub

End Module
```

This will work because now you're passing around a concrete reference to an instance of `form_Main`. My problem with this approach, however, is that your module should really have no notion of `form_Main` in the first place. My initial recommendation was going to be progress reporting via `Progress/IProgress`, but it's only appropriate in cases where you're processing a collection of some kind, whereas you're working with disparate database operations, so a better design would be as follows:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class form_Main

  Private Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click() Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click
    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf Me.RunManualScan)

    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub RunManualScan()
    ' We know this will be running on a background thread.
    Dim workResult1 = DatabaseWork.SomeWork()

    Me.SetTextBoxInfo("Report Back - Step " & workResult1)

    Dim workResult2 = DatabaseWork.OtherWork()

    Me.SetTextBoxInfo("Report Back - Step " & workResult2)
  End Sub

  Public Sub SetTextBoxInfo(stringValue As String)
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() Me.TextBox.Text = stringValue)
  End Sub

End Class

' You could use a Module, but it
' pollutes IntelliSense more than Class.
Public NotInheritable Class DatabaseWork

  Public Shared Function SomeWork() As Int32
    Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Return 1
  End Function

  Public Shared Function OtherWork() As Int32
    Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Return 2
  End Function

End Class
```

Now we have better separation of concerns: the "database" only knows about the fine-grained database operations, and the form knows how to put those database operations together and update itself when necessary. It's still ugly though due to `Thread` and `BeginInvoke` use. .NET 4.5 provides better mechanisms of composing asynchronous operations which allow us to rewrite the above as follows:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class form_Main

  Private Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click() Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click
    Me.ExecuteManualScan()
  End Sub

  ' Note the Async modifier.
  Private Async Sub ExecuteManualScan()
    ' The delegate passed to Task.Run executes on
    ' a thread pool (background) thread. Await'ing
    ' a task transitions us back to the original thread.
    ' Note that it is good practice to use Task.Run for
    ' CPU-bound work, but since we're stuck with blocking
    ' database operations, it will have to do in this case.
    Dim workResult1 = Await Task.Run(AddressOf DatabaseWork.SomeWork)

    ' Note the lack of BeginInvoke - we're already on the UI thread.
    Me.TextBox.Text = "Report Back - Step " & workResult1

    ' Note that the delegate is declared slightly differently.
    ' While functionally similar to the first call, this version
    ' allows you to pass arguments to the method if necessary.
    Dim workResult2 = Await Task.Run(Function() DatabaseWork.OtherWork())

    Me.TextBox.Text = "Report Back - Step " & workResult2
  End Sub

End Class
```

**EDIT**

If you absolutely must report progress from a long-running operation, since .NET 4.0 `System.Progress(Of T)/IProgress(Of T)` is the recommended way of doing so in a caller-agnostic fashion. Note that it's a generic type so it is ultimately up to you what it is exactly that you want to report throughout the processing - and while the convention is `Int32` denoting progress percentage, you could also use something completely arbitrary like `String`s, for example.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Public Class form_Main

  Private Sub toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan_Click() Handles toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Click
    Me.ExecuteManualScan()
  End Sub

  Private Async Sub ExecuteManualScan()
    ' Ensure that the next scan operation cannot
    ' be started until this one is complete by
    ' disabling the relevant UI elements.
    Me.toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Enabled = False

    Try
      Me.TextBox.Text = "Starting ..."

      ' When you create an instance of Progress, it captures
      ' the current SynchronizationContext, and will raise
      ' the ProgressChanged event on that context, meaning
      ' that if it's created on the UI thread, the progress
      ' handler callback will automatically be marshalled back
      ' to the UI thread for you, so you no longer need Invoke.
      Dim progress As New Progress(Of Int32)

      ' Update the UI when progress is reported.
      AddHandler progress.ProgressChanged,
        Sub(s, progressPercentage) Me.TextBox.Text = String.Format("Progress: {0}%.", progressPercentage)

      Dim workResult = Await Task.Run(Function() DatabaseWork.LongWork(progress))

      Me.TextBox.Text = "Result: " & workResult
    Finally
      Me.toolStripItem_Run_Manual_Scan.Enabled = True
    End Try
  End Sub

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class DatabaseWork

  Public Shared Function LongWork(progress As IProgress(Of Int32)) As Int32
    Dim progressPercentage = 0

    For i = 0 To 100 - 1
      ' Simulate some work.
      Thread.Sleep(10)

      progressPercentage += 1

      progress.Report(progressPercentage)
    Next

    Return 42
  End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Firstly I want to say 'Thank You' for taking the time to reply my question... I really appreciate it :) I like and understand the last part of your answer and have it set up in my application and its working great. I would still like to know how to pass a value directly from within a long running process back to the main UI to show progress (if the first part of your answer isn't the correct way to do it) but that can wait for another day as I have no need for it now.

Comment: @jaminben, happy to help and it's good to hear that it makes sense now. Sorry if I led you astray with some of my comments on the question - it's difficult to discuss design principles without showing code. In terms of reporting progress from a long-running operation, I have added a new section to my answer showing exactly that. Hopefully it will come in handy.

Comment: Cool... I'll try that out later.   `Thank You`.