# How do I get progress reported from a DLL?

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I've read through this article, and tried to setup my application as closely to it as I could, but it still doesn't work:

[Updating label from module in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712169/updating-label-from-module-in-another-thread/24713646#24713646)

In my case, I've abstracted my database operation to a DLL, and would like to pass the reference to my progress bar to the library function to update as it does its work. It's my understanding that this is exactly the sort of thing that the Async/Await interface was invented for. However, the exact syntax of the calls eludes me. I have:

```
Private Async Sub ButtonImport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonImport.Click

    Dim importer As DatabaseDataLib.Importation = New DatabaseDataLib.Importation
    Dim progress_indicator As Progress(Of Integer) = New Progress(Of Integer)(AddressOf DisplayProgress)
    Dim success As Integer = Await Task.Run(Function() importer.ImportDatasetAsync(x, y, z, a, progress_indicator))

    If success = 1 Then
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Something went wrong!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub DisplayProgress(percentage As Integer)
    Debug.Print("I'm being called!")
    ToolStripProgressBarImport.Value = percentage
End Sub
```

The function signature, in the library, looks like this:

```
Public Function ImportDatasetAsync(x As Integer, y As String, z As String, _
    a As String, progress_indicator As IProgress(Of Integer)) As Integer
```

In this function, there are 2 loops for every one of the ~18K records. As each one is processed, there's a call to the `progress_indicator` callback:

```
progress_indicator.Report(counter / objects.Count * 100)
```

This will compile, but then throw this error:

```
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Apparently, this `Task.Run(Function() ...)` notation is making the runtime crap out, so I changed the call to this:

```
Dim success As Integer = Await importer.ImportDatasetAsync(x, y, z, a, progress_indicator)
```

And the function signature to this:

```
Public Function ImportDatasetAsync(x As Integer, y As String, z As String, _
    a As String, progress_indicator As IProgress(Of Integer)) As Task(Of Integer)
```

This will pass the Intellisense check, but fail actual compilation unless I get rid of my `Return 1`, since it complains that an `Integer` is not a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)`. This seems the lesser of my worries at the moment, but maybe that's significant. Getting rid of the return value will allow the program to finally run. The `progress_indicator` function gets called, but the calls are stacked, or serialized. (I don't know the right term.) When the function finally finishes, the calls to the callback finally execute. I get a hundred or so, and then a stack overflow. I don't know how to set this call stack up so that I get the behavior I expect.

I'm kind of lost. I've studied examples around the internet for about 2 days now, and I can't find the magic incantation that will make this work. I'm missing something fundamental, I guess. It sometimes seems, in the things I'm reading, that I should be breaking out the actual database calls to a separate function that I make Async, and leave the update of the Progress object in the main loop, but, if that's true, it's almost a level of abstraction too deep to fool with, and I'll try a different method of getting a stupid progress bar. Sheesh!

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the posted snippets.  Use Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions and show us the call stack when the debugger breaks, along with the code where the exception was thrown.

Comment: I've left something out! As it sits, it doesn't throw an error. My long-running function works, spits out a lot of `Debug.Print`'s right next to the `progress_indicator.Report()`'s, but doesn't execute them UNTIL THE FUNCTION RETURNS. (Sorry, I forgot about this, because it takes so long to run my function that I've been killing it.) Anyway, then I get a couple hundred "I got called!" debug statements from the callback function, and a stack overflow. So the Progress callback calls get stacked, and I don't know how to write this so that they execute in parallel.

Comment: I edited the original post.