# Async Await Task.Run update a modal form throw Exception

Tags: vb.net

I have two form
its run fine, but if I press cancel button of modal form then display error.
Can any one help me to solve the problem?
My code is given below:

1)

```
Public Class FRMWait

    Public MinValue As Integer = 0
    Public MaxValue As Integer = 100

    Private Sub FRMWait_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With Me
            .ProgressBa1.MinimumValue = .MinValue
            .ProgressBa1.MaximumValue = .MaxValue
        End With
    End Sub

    Public Sub UpdateBar(ByVal Progress As Integer)
        With Me
            .ProgressBarControlProgress.value = Progress
        End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButtonCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonCancel.Click
        With Me
            .DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

2)

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class FRMTest
    Private WaitForm As New FRMWait
    Private _CTS As CancellationTokenSource

    Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        With Me
            .WaitForm = New FRMWait
            ._CTS = New CancellationTokenSource()
            Try
                Await Task.Run(Sub() RunLongTask())
                .WaitForm.ShowDialog()
                If .WaitForm.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel Then
                    ._CTS.Cancel()
                End If
            Catch Exp As Exception
                MsgBox(Exp.Message)
            Finally
                If ._CTS IsNot Nothing Then ._CTS = Nothing
            End Try
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub RunLongTask()
        With Me
            .WaitForm.MinValue = 0
            .WaitForm.MaxValue = 100
            For i = 0 To 100
                If ._CTS.IsCancellationRequested Then
                    Await Task.Delay(1000)
                    Exit For
                End If
                .WaitForm.UpdateBar(i)
                Await Task.Delay(100)
            Next
            .WaitForm.Close()
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: How could we possibly help you without telling us what the error type and message is?

Comment: What's the error? I think dialog will only show when the RunLongTask is done. Also, [you can only change the UI from the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712169/updating-label-from-module-in-another-thread).

Comment: No, Its run fine, but when i press Cancel button then its display error. How, I can send my project file?

Comment: error: ---- System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Progress1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: `RunLongTask` really needs to be a `Function` that returns a `Task`, and not a `Sub`.  Then you can properly `await` it without needing to use `Task.Run`.  This will allow you to handle any exceptions correctly.